# how to check jwt login in node with express

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I'm trying to create a login route for my api. The algorithm is as follows:

First check if the user exists in the database(if not, send 404 error).
Then I check if the password parameter in the query is the same as in the database(if not, send a 400 error).
Finally create a token and send it.

Here is the code:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next){ 
User.getUserByNick(req.params.nick,function(err, rows){
    if(err){ 
        res.json(err);
    }               
    else if(!f.isEmpty(rows)){
        res.status(404);
        res.json({
            error: 404,
            message: 'Authentication failed. User not found.'
            });
    } 
    else{
        res.json(rows);
        if(res.password != req.params.password){
            res.status(400);
            res.json({
                error: 400,
                message: 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'
                });
        } 
        else{
            var token = jwt.sign(rows, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresInMinutes: 1440 // expires in 24 hours
            });
            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Enjoy your token!',
                    token: token
                });
            }
        }
    });     
});
```

But when I try to use the route node crashes. I get the next error in console

```
/api/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:79
    throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
    ^
ValidationError: "value" must be an object
```

I don't know why, getUserByNick works nice and it returns [] when the user is not found. Otherwise it sends the json with the rows. So I think it may be when I make rows.password.

Comment: Actually I don't show your code deeply. But what is my first question is when you do not have defined parameter named Nick, why/how are you trying to use req.params.nick ??

Comment: Its inside the body of the Post request. Should I use req.body instead of params?

Comment: Yup exactly. You should also use any kind of body parser to do so!!

Answer (score 0):

Even if it is not direct answer to your question, I see that problem lies not here exactly. I think main thing you should do first, it is find a way how to debug you code. If you can see what inside req and res, you would not ask where to take variable. You just will find it yourself. If you are not familiar with debuggers, try to use visual studio code. It is free and powerful. https://code.visualstudio.com/ Then find a documentation how to debug javascript.

If you want half solution, you can try to print variables to console:

```
console.log(req);
console.log(res);
```

Browse you input, and you will find answer to your question.